# can't parse JSON data to interface with rxjs

Tags: json, typescript, interface, rxjs

I have a webSocket that I get data from my server. I created a rx Subject MessageEvent that return the data.

But, on my observable, I can console log my object and it print the json data, but I can't access any property, it return undefined.

```
export interface Message {
request: string;
subscription: string,
}

@Injectable()
export class SocketProvider {

public message: Subject<Message>;

constructor(private socket: WebsocketProvider) {
  console.log('Hello SocketProvider Provider');
  this.message = <Subject<Message>>socket
  .connect('ws://192.168.0.110:8081')
  .map((response: MessageEvent): Message => {
    let data = response.data;
    return data;
  })
}

}
```

and usage:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    console.log('ionViewDidEnter ConfigsInputsPage');
      this.subscribtion =  this.socket.message.subscribe(msg => {
      this.message = msg;
      console.log("Response From webSocket server: " + msg);
      console.log(msg.request);
    });
    this.socket.message.next(this.enterMessage);
}

private enterMessage = { 
  request: 'configs',
  subscription: 'suscribe'
}
```

Comment: It returns `undefined` where?

Comment: console.log("Response From webSocket server: " + msg); return the json data but console.log(msg.request); return undefine

Comment: Then where do you initialize `this.enterMessage`?

Comment: just next to it, just added edit to my post.

Comment: add your sample response here. 

console.log("Response From webSocket server: " + msg);   which means what you got this line.

Comment: yes. I got my JSON DATA : `{"request":"configs","subscription":"suscribe"}` that refelct what I was sending to the server trough next function.

Comment: one clue: on ` this.subscribtion =  this.socket.message.subscribe(msg => {`, intellisence of visual code tel me that type of msg is :Message, but if i do:  `console.log("Response type " + typeof msg); ` It print string...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. foud that I add to parse json again in socket.ts:

```
constructor(private socket: WebsocketProvider) {
  console.log('Hello SocketProvider Provider');
  this.message = <Subject<Message>>socket
  .connect('ws://192.168.0.110:8081')
  .map((response: MessageEvent): Message => {
      let data = JSON.parse(response.data); //  <----------
      return data;
  })
}
```